# Returning to the main function after job completion in java

Tags: java, printing

I have the codes here:
For the main class:

```
 PrintingOperation printnew = new PrintingOperation();
 printnew.PrintingOperation(newfile);

 System.out.println("The file is to be deleted and will return from the start");

 File toDelete = listOfFiles[0]; //This output the full path of the file to be deleted
 System.out.println(toDelete); //I confirmed that it is a full path
 toDelete.delete(); //The problem occurs here -> It does not delete the file
 System.out.println("The file is deleted");
```

For the printing service:

```
   public String PrintingOperation(String file_name){

    System.out.println("The file name is: " + file_name);
    PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    PdfDecoder decodePdf = new PdfDecoder(true);
    try {
    decodePdf.openPdfFile(file_name);
    FontMappings.setFontReplacements();

 } catch (Exception e) {
    //...
 }

//Setting the attributes
    PrintRequestAttributeSet attributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    JobName jobName = new JobName(file_name, null);
    attributeSet.add(jobName);
    attributeSet.add(new Copies(1)); //NUMBER OF COPIES
    attributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4); // Paper size : ISO_A4 or NA_LEGAL
    attributeSet.add(Chromaticity.COLOR); //COLOR or MONOCHROME
    decodePdf.setPrintAutoRotateAndCenter(false);

    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, attributeSet);
    for(PrintService s : services) {
      System.out.println(s.getName());
    }
        PrintService printingDevice = null; 
    for(PrintService s : services) {
      if(s.getName().equals("Brother MFC-5890CN Printer")) { //Change it to the printer available
           printingDevice = s; 
      }
    }
    PdfBook pdfBook = new PdfBook(decodePdf, printingDevice, attributeSet);
    SimpleDoc doc = new SimpleDoc(pdfBook, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, null);
    DocPrintJob printJob = printingDevice.createPrintJob();
    JobCompleteMonitor monitor = new JobCompleteMonitor();
    printJob.addPrintJobListener(monitor);
    try {
      printJob.print(doc, attributeSet);
    } catch (PrintException e) {
        //...
    }
    monitor.waitForJobCompletion();


    System.out.println("Exiting printing process");      
    return null;
}
private static class JobCompleteMonitor extends PrintJobAdapter {

    private boolean completed = false;

    @Override
    public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        signalCompletion();
    }

    @Override
    public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        signalCompletion();
    }

    @Override
    public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        signalCompletion();
    }

    @Override
    public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        signalCompletion();
    }

    private void signalCompletion() {

synchronized (JobCompleteMonitor.this) {

        completed = true;

        JobCompleteMonitor.this.notify();
}

  }

public synchronized void waitForJobCompletion() {

  try {

while (!completed) {

    wait();

}

  } catch (InterruptedException e) {

 }


}
}
```

Once the program reached the

> printJob.print(doc, attributeSet)

The printer will start its operation and will print the document. However, it automatically returns to the main method and will not delete the file being printed. I placed the function for waiting for the completion of the print job but it still returns to the main method without waiting for the print job to finished.

**The question is**, how will I only return to the main method after the printing process is finished and will delete the file after the printing process? I used the system.exit() but I don't want the program to terminate, but I just want to return to the main method after the print job is finished to execute the remaining line of codes in the main method. I hope someone can help me regarding this.

Note: I also viewed the difference between return and system.exit() as well as the halt. I also checked that in order to delete the file, I need the full path for it to be deleted and I found out that I already placed the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you just delete the file in the job? I think add deleting code to the job is better. Or you can add a flag to the job when it has been finished, and add waiting code in main method (for example while true) to wait the flag be true, then do delete.

Comment: I tried to do that but I can't find a way to get any value if the print job is completed. If i got any signal or value if the print job is completed, that will be the only time to return to the main function. Do you know any way to get a value if the print job is finished?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the simplest answer for this one. It is only because I did not close the pdfFile.

The decodePdf.closePdfFile(); should be added before returning so that the file will be deleted.

:) Hope this will help other people :)